# How to get the number of cuts and the actual cuts that have been added to SCIP using a conshdlr in C++

Tags: linear-programming, scip, integer-programming

My scip solution log is showing that the number of cuts that have been added are 10 but when I try to get the number using 
`SCIPgetNCuts(scip)`
I always get 0.

In addition to this, is there a way to get all the cuts that have been added into a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to figure this one out.

Just create an additional data structure (like an std::vector) which will hold the cuts( basically the `LProws` and you might have to create some supplemental datastrcutureas to hold the actual cut info (say graphs info etc)). Pass this data-structure(s) between the pricer and the constraint handler and add the new variables to the existing constraints and the cuts.